# how do i skip part of each line while reading from file in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and not able to figure out how do i accomplish this.

Suppose file.txt contains following

```
iron man 1
iron woman 2
man ant 3
woman wonder 4
```

i want to read this file into dictionary in the below format

```
dict = { 'iron' : ['man', 'woman'], 'man' : ['ant'], 'woman' : ['wonder'] }
```

That is the last part in each line being omitted while writing to dictionary.

My second question is can i read this file to dictionary in a way such that

```
dict2 = { 'iron' : [('man', '1'), ('woman', '2')], 'man' : [('ant', '3')], 'woman' : [('wonder', '4')] } .
```

That is key *iron* will have 2 values but these 2 values being individual tuple.

Second question is for implementation of uniform cost search so that i can access *iron* child *man* and *woman* and cost for these children being 1 and 2

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go both the parts of your question...Being new to python just spend some time with it like your grilfriend and you will know how it behaves

```
with open ('file.txt','r') as data:
    k = data.read()
    lst = k.splitlines()

print lst
dic = {}
dic2 = {}
for i in lst:
    p=i.split(" ")
    if str(p[0]) in dic.keys():
        dic[p[0]].append(p[2])
        dic2[p[0]].append((p[1],p[2]))
    else:
        dic[p[0]] = [p[1]]
        dic2[p[0]] = [(p[1],p[2])]


print dic
print dic2
```

Comment: Perfect :), one minor change is dic[p[0]].append(p[1]) in the if loop. Thank you.

Comment: i did up vote it, but since i haven't yet earned 15 reputations my up vote wont be visible to public

Answer (score 0):

you can use `collections.defaultdict`:

you 1st answer

```
import collections.defaultdict
my_dict = cillections.defaultdict(list)
with open('your_file') as f:
    for line in f:
         line = line.strip().split()
         my_dict[line[0]].append(line[1])

print my_dict
```

Taking above example, you might able to solve 2nd question.

Comment: Got it working, thanks. You have used line.strip().split() but even line.split() worked, so any why extra call to strip ?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, what you want to do is read each line, split it using white spaces and use a simple if rule to control how you add it to your dictionary:

```
my_dict = {}
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()

for line in content.split('\n'):
    item = line.split()
    if item[0] not in my_dict:
        my_dict[item[0]] = [item[1]]
    else:
        my_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])
```

The second question is pretty much the same, only with a slightly different assignment:

```
my_dict2 = {}
for line in content.split('\n'):
    item = line.split()
    if item[0] not in my_dict:
        my_dict[item[0]] = [(item[1], item[2])]
    else:
        my_dict[item[0]].append((item[1], item[2]))
```

Comment: i am getting IndexError, if i change content.split('\n') to content.splitlines() it works. Not sure what is wrong with your way, even i printed item[0] in your original code, it contained valid elements of list yet getting following error - if item[0] not in my_dict:
IndexError: list index out of range